# How to open a popup window with an external url in a chrome app? (like window.open with _blank)

Tags: google-chrome-app

I need to open an url on a new and single tab chrome window, as you would normally do with window.open and "_blank", but when done inside a chrome app, the url is opened in a new tab of an already running chrome, ignoring all the window features options (width, height, etc).

Are we doing something wrong or is this a chrome app constrain? Any way to solve it?

Best regards
Sergio

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Use a proper API to open a tab, [`chrome.browser.openTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/browser), but that doesn't give you an ability to open it in a separate window. Such an option would probably be a nice addition, you can try [submitting](https://crbug.com) a feature request for it.
2. [Open an app window](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create) with a local HTML file that embeds the required web content inside a [`<webview>`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview). You then have full control over appearance, but lose access to browser's conveniences like cookie/password store of the current user, and have to implement some things yourself like dialog boxes.

I'm afraid a Chrome app cannot interact with the browser itself in a more detailed way by design.